# Smooth Scrolling for scrollIntoView();

Tags: javascript, onclick, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

I have a radio button. When clicked upon, I make the page scroll to a div. That's working perfectly.

Here's the HTML for the Radio Button:

```
<input type="radio" id="tab" onclick="document.getElementById('mydivID').scrollIntoView();" name="tabs1" class="input">
```

The only thing I want more is for that scroll to be a smooth scroll. Is that possible?

Answer (score 11):

```
document.getElementById('mydivID')
        .scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
```

Let me know how that goes

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't seem to work. Probably some HTML issues due to the quotes? I even tried single quotes for "smooth" but that didn't work either. `<input type="radio" id="tab" onclick="document.getElementById('mydivID').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});" name="tabs1" class="input">`

Comment: Well appernlty it only works in firefox for the moment. I think there is a polyfill here https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution that worked for me, first get the element you want to scroll your view to then apply a smooth behavior:

```
    const elm = document.getElementById(id)
    elm.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

make sure to install this [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) (npm package):

```
    # npm install smoothscroll-polyfill --save
```